# Chrome debugger stop JavaScript function call

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, javascript-debugger

In Chome debugger (developer tools) if you delete an element, such as a img tag, it disappears from the page. If you delete a script tag however, functions from the script can still be called dynamically.

I understand that the loaded page is in memory, but is there still a way to stop a JavaScript function from being called after the web page is loaded?

Comment: Have you tried using breakpoints in google dev tools? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints

Comment: I have been using break points to "pause on attribute modification", however the attribute, in this case a "class", is getting changed and then the pause occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't destroy a function because it lives in memory. You could do it programmatically as bellow

```
    var test = function() {
    //code here
    }
```

and any time you want you can set the function as null

```
test = null
```

I hope it helps

Comment: This looks like its on the right path.  I found the JS function thats changing the "class" element, but (in the console) when I set "var test = b.function();" i get an error that says "b not defined". Is there a parent function i need to set first?

Comment: I don't understand what is b.

Comment: apparently the name of the function im working with. I am trying to set var test = to a function, correct? Do i need code in the brackets or do I just set var test = to the name of the function i.e. "var test = <nameOfFunction>.function();"